# Passing array to lightning-modal is being flattened

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service

I am trying pass in a simple array to a base `lightning-modal` component.

```js
import MyModal from 'c/myModal'; //This is extending LightningModal from 'lightning/modal'
 
options = ['a','b','c'];

async openModal(event)
    {
        const result = await MyModal.open({
            size: 'small',
            options: this.options
        });
    }
```

And this is my JavaScript for that modal:

```js
_options;

    @api
    get options()
    {
        return this._options;
    }

    set options(value)
    {
        // When I debug value at this point, my array is intact
        this._options = value;
    }
```

Here is the HTML template:

```html
<template>
{_options}
</template>
```

When I output `_options` directly to the HTML template, I would expect it to output `[object object]` signifying that it is an array. However, I seeing this `a,b,c` as though that it is being flattened to a string. I don't want this to happen. I have traced the flattening to some internal `aura_prod.js` code that is doing this and I don't understand why:

```js
function(e) {
    return null == e ? "" : String(e)
}
```

Why is Salesforce doing this?

Comment: How are options and merchIds being wired up in the template, or how are they set? What's the open function look like? There's a lot of missing context.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have added updates, hopefully that helps

Comment: @sfdcfox I think I have figured it out. When you pass in an array that just has primitive values, it appears that Salesforce will try and flatten out the array to display it. However, the actual array itself in the JavaScript controller state is still in its original Array form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be newer behavior. I recall that objects (e.g. Array) previously always formatted as if rendered by `Object.prototype.toString`. This appears to be a fix to produce more readable output for simple merge fields. However, it doesn't work in all cases. Example:

```
  options = ['a','b','c'];
```

```
<template>
    {options}
    <div iterator:it={options} key={it.value}>{it}</div>
</template>
```

Outputs:

> a,b,c
>
> [object Object]
>
> [object Object]
>
> [object Object]

However, as you've observed, it's only for plain old objects that have a way to convert to a string in a meaningful manner.

Note that in any case, the data is still in its original form in the controller class. You can still use the data as you expect, as demonstrated in the code above.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I wish SF had this documented somewhere